# bytes to string or int

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I make a query in python to Mysql of a BLOB file and I convert it into an array to be able to manipulate. The problem is that it returns this type of ndarray:

```
arr = [b'[[NaN, NaN], [-0.15641936086712763, NaN], [NaN, NaN]]']
```

I don't know how to convert it to be able to manipulate it

It is of type bytes and I try to convert it to string and I can't either.

```
print(arr.decode("utf-8"))
```

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do `print(arr[0].decode("utf-8"))`? You're trying to decode the array itself rather than the `bytes` item it contains.

Comment: `arr = [b'[[NaN, NaN], [-0.15641936086712763, NaN], [NaN, NaN]]']` is not a `numpy.ndarray`. That is a list, with a single element, which is a bytes object. It looks like that string may have been the `repr` or part of the `repr` of some ndarray. I doubt the code you posted accuratly represents what you are actually working with, given your error. Please post the result of `print(repr(arr))`

Comment: I *suspect* that you simply dumped the string representation of some array into your MySql blob. That's a problem. Don't do that. Use an actual serialization format, e.g. the one provide by `numpy.save` would be the most portable and efficient for working with `numpy.ndarray` objects

Comment: ...so, it's too late to fix this when you're getting your data out of the database. You need to fix the way you're putting your data _into_ the database.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave can be processed by [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

```
arr = [b'[[NaN, NaN], [-0.15641936086712763, NaN], [NaN, NaN]]']
resultArray = [json.loads(a.decode()) for a in arr];
```